# C program to replace a pattern "find" with "replace" in a textfile as input and output file should have the replaced pattern

Tags: c, replace

i searched on net but not getting the exact idea of how to do it as the code m being able to write is just for a single occurence of the pattern but if there are different lines of occurence of that pattern??

Comment: Do you have code now that can read through a text file, line by line?

Comment: Could you please clarify:  are you searching for fixed text or for a pattern?  Do you need a regular expression engine?  Do you have acces to a regular expression library?  Which platform/compiler are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: no m looking for a fixed text m using unix plaform. Suppose my file is like :1 xyz 23
      2 xyz 45  then the output should be 1 abc 23
                                          2 abc 45

Comment: @cdarke: i have tried a code but i think there is something wrong in this actually m unaware of "c" file commands m more good in c++

Comment: can anyone please provide the complete code based on this sample output as i have told above?

Comment: If you can do it for a single occurence, just do it again until no occurence is replaced and you have your answer.

Comment: should i paste my code wat m trying so that anybody can help??

Answer (score 4):

If you are on a Unix or similar system (like Linux or MacOS X) then you already have a command line program to do this: `sed`.

Otherwise you have to read from the original file and write to a new file, replacing the text while reading and writing. After that you have to rename the new file as the old original file.

As for the actual finding of the text, if it's a fixed string you can use e.g. `strstr`, other wise look into [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions).

**Edit:** How to do it with [`sed(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
$ sed -i 's/xyz/abc/g' infile.txt
```

The above command will read `infile.txt`, replace all occurrences of the text `xyz` with `abc` and write it back to `infile.txt`.

**Edit:** How to search/replace:

```
FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
FILE *output = fopen("temp.txt", "w");

char buffer[512];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) != NULL)
{
    /* The text to find */
    static const char text_to_find[] = "xyz";

    /* The text to replace it with */
    static const char text_to_replace[] = "abc";

    char *pos = strstr(buffer, text_to_find);
    if (pos != NULL)
    {
        /* Allocate memory for temporary buffer */
        char *temp = calloc(
            strlen(buffer) - strlen(text_to_find) + strlen(text_to_replace) + 1, 1);

        /* Copy the text before the text to replace */
        memcpy(temp, buffer, pos - buffer);

        /* Copy in the replacement text */
        memcpy(temp + (pos - buffer), text_to_replace, strlen(text_to_replace));

        /* Copy the remaining text from after the replace text */
        memcpy(temp + (pos - buffer) + strlen(text_to_replace),
               pos + strlen(text_to_find),
               1 + strlen(buffer) - ((pos - buffer) + strlen(text_to_find)));

        fputs(temp, output);

        free(temp);
    }
    else
        fputs(buffer, output);
}

fclose(output);
fclose(input);

/* Rename the temporary file to the original file */
rename("input.txt", "temp.txt");
```

This code has been [tested to work](http://ideone.com/2kgeW).

**Note:** If you don't know what *pointer arithmetic* is, then the above code might be very hard to follow and understand, and you just have to trust me that it does what it should. :)

Comment: thanks a lot ur code worked exactly what i wanted..thank u so so much:):)

Comment: Great one, but unfortunately the only problem with the code in http://ideone.com/gR7jjk is it can replace single instance of a word.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Just call `strstr` in a loop: `while (pos != NULL) { /* all other code */ pos = strstr(pos, text_to_find); }`