# C: memcpy() with NULL characters

Tags: visual-c++, null, memcpy

I have a C++ code that will print text and images. Both are working okay when they are ran separately. Now, I want to merge the printing so I can embed the image anywhere I want.

```
data = "TEXT [LOGO] TEXT";
```

Suppose, I have the data above. For data like this what I wanted to do here, is to replace the [LOGO] with the actual data for the receipt printing. Image data are stored in a file (ESC Pos Commands Plus image data).

Sample Image Data in a text file..

> 1b40 1b61 011b 3308 1b2a 01f0 003f 7f7f
>   ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
>   ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
>   ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff fefe fcfc f8f8
>   f0f0 e0e1 c1c3 8707 0f0f 0000 0000 0000

I reused a search and replace function.. 
[from this link...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280008/c-program-to-replace-a-pattern-find-with-replace-in-a-textfile-as-input-and)

For simplicity, let's just refer to a simple `memcpy` call...

```
char *temp = (char*) calloc(dataLength,dataLength * sizeof(char*));
memcpy(temp, logoBuffer, logoSize);
```

Now the problem is that logoBuffer contains a lot of 'NULL characters'. And during the copy the data was cut.

Is there any workaround for this? ran out of ideas...

Comment: How is `logobuffer` constructed - perhaps fix that

Comment: `calloc(dataLength,dataLength * sizeof(char*))` does not sound right. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Exactly, do you understand the `sizeof` operator?, do you know the difference between `calloc()` and `malloc()`? Do you understand what a `void *` pointer is in [tag:c]? Are you aware of the difference between [tag:c] and [tag:c++]? And also *I have a C script*, it's a really horrible thing to read. There is no such thing as C scripts.

Comment: Also, what would the string representation of the `null` (*please note the lowercase `null` is not the same as `NULL` which is a pointer*)? It's used as the terminating character and it doesn't have a printable representation. So I suppose the question is, how you intend to print the binary image data?

Comment: You just made it wrose. If it's [tag:c++] then, 1. Do not tag as [tag:c]. 2. Do not use `calloc` use `new`, and probably you should not be using raw data buffers in [tag:c++] because there are more high level ways of doing things..

Comment: Oh, and you should read the printer manual. Perhaps you can simply save the logo data into the printers memory and simply pass a string to the appropriate command so the printer can load the data from it's internal memory and print it for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for the inputs.. iharob... i don't really know much about C/C++ but hopefully I'll be able to crack this thing.. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you want to store binary data in a text file. You can't generally do that because binary data is not text data<sup>1</sup>, although text data is binary data. You need to make your file binary and read/write to it accordingly by using the appropriate funcion or function parameters. Other than that you seem to be having problems with [c](/questions/tagged/c) or perhaps [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) languages which are different, read this link [c](/questions/tagged/c) to understand.

You for example, do the dynamic memory allocation wrong, you are just allocating more space than you apparently want to thus not causing any visible problem. But the fact that you allocate the wrong size means that you might easily do something that would have very tragic results, to understand why I say this read about the concept of *undefined behavior*.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Not every byte has a textual representation, thus not every sequence of bytes can be used or thought of as text</sub>.

Comment: geez.. really need to do a lot of reading.. so I guess, need to handle this in a different manner.. thank you so much for your inputs.

Comment: @severinolorillajr Why is it that you want to use a low level language? Why don't you use a ready made driver instead? Is it a "*special*" operating system for which the manufacturer does not distribute a driver? What is the language you wrote the rest of the program with?

Comment: this is actually a POS system.. don't have much idea about everything yet. But we are using Visual C++ and VB for this one.. one of the challenges here is that we are using a dot matrix printer.. the codes that I have here, is already working.. just need to find away to process them as one (if possible).